# Country_picker not displaying a selected country: Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm having a problem of displaying a selected country back to the search bar from the country picker Flutter package. Could someone please help? Thank you

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers, sized_box_for_whitespace
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 250,
                  child: SearchBar(
                    onChanged: print,
                    backgroundColor:
                        const MaterialStatePropertyAll(Color(0xffE1E8F6)),
                    leading: const Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: Color(0xffFF5A5A),
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                    side: const MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                        BorderSide(color: Color(0xffC5C3C6))),
                    hintText: 'Worldwide',
                    textStyle: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall),
                    onTap: () => showCountryPicker(
                      context: context,
                      showPhoneCode: false,
                      countryListTheme: CountryListThemeData(
                          inputDecoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
                              hintText: 'Search a country',
                              hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                borderSide:
                                    const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffC5C3C6)),
                              )),
                          searchTextStyle:
                              Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          bottomSheetHeight: 400),
                      onSelect: (Country country) {
                        print('Select country: ${country.displayName}');
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
```

Think I'm missing something probably from the `onSelect` property but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the selected country back in the search bar,you need to maintain the selected country's information and use a TextEditingController to control the text displayed in the search bar.

**Step 1 : Define a TextEditingController and the selected country variable:**

```
TextEditingController _searchController = TextEditingController();
Country _selectedCountry;
```

**Step 2 : Initialize the _searchController's text and update it when a country is selected.**

```
 onSelect: (Country country) {
       setState(() {
      _selectedCountry = country;
      _searchController.text = country.displayName;
    });
   },
```

**Step 3 :Attach the _searchController to the SearchBar's controller property & As per requirement update the hintText of the SearchBar based on whether a country is selected or not.**

```
SearchBar(
  // ... other properties
  controller: _searchController,
  hintText: _selectedCountry != null
      ? _selectedCountry.displayName
      : 'Worldwide',
  // ... other properties
),
```